# how to change file permission to view image

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, file-permissions

For some reason when I SCP'd my files to my server an image did not get the same permission as other files that were uploaded.  For this reason I am getting a 403 forbidden error.

My file permissions look like:

[image]

How can I set the permission of ima-1.png to have the same permissions as the other files above it?

Comment: The lazy way: `chmod a+r ima-1.png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run the command:

chmod 644 ima-1.png

That will provide the same permissions as the files above it.